# How to store HTML data in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm trying to crawl the web and store HTML data on MongoDB using Java. Unfortunetely while storing data, MongoDB drivers nulling the data and stores empty field for HTML data.

When I get the first 500 chars of HTML data, I can store/upsert it without a problem so I think something in HTML (or Javascript in it) corrupts the command sent to MongoDB and MongoDB stores empty data instead of HTML. (**EDIT**: Also I've tried with 40.000 and 50.000 chars and 40.000 was OK but 50.000 char data didn't show up on MongoDB) Should I use something else for storing HTML/JavaScript data?

Here is my code snippet

```
BasicDBObject savedDoc = new BasicDBObject();
savedDoc.put("url_ID", objURL.get("_id"));
savedDoc.put("cnt", content); //Content field
savedDoc.put("st", 0);
collection.update(new BasicDBObject().append("url_ID", objURL.get("_id")), savedDoc, true, false);
```

Comment: Is `content` a String. If so, this should work.

Comment: @Thilo yes it's String, it's working if I cut it with substring.. (I tried for 500 chars)

Comment: @duffymo Do you answer for sharing and help or just for earning points? You may not bother, thank you. Also here is my code and that's all. So it seems to be because of MongoDB's Java Driver or I'm missing something like escaping string etc.

Comment: There should be no size limit on the String, and there is no need for you to escape manually. Are you on the latest version of the Java driver?

Comment: @Thilo I'm using 2.8.0 version of Java drivers. It seems to be latest stable.. Can it be because of wrong charset or something like this?

Comment: Why don't you try with a 1000-char length `"aaaa..."`? That will tell you if it's a size problem or content problem. Anyway if it's a string it should work. You are passing the string value and the driver should do what's necesary.

Comment: @helios I did it but also it doesn't shows if it's size or content problem. I tried with 1000 char length HTML and works but what if the problem occurs after 1000 char on HTML?

If it can be a size problem, how can I set MongoDB field size? I couldn't find anything according to this..

Comment: MongoDB documents have a limit of 16MB so pretty sure you're not hitting the limit with a String of 50000 chars.
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Documents

What error are you getting?